# how can I add a prefix string in the filename when upload a file using qq.FileUploader

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

my code is like this, how can i add the prefix like "123_" to the front of the filename when the user uploads like 1.jpg, and then change it to 123_1.jpg to the server?

```
                  <script type="text/javascript">                                         
                      var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({                            
                            element: document.getElementById('file-uploader'),            
                            allowedExtensions: ["jpg", "pdf"],         
                            template: '<div class="qq-uploader">' +                       
                                      '<div class="qq-upload-drop-area"><span>drag the files to here to upload</span></div>' +
                                      '<div class="qq-upload-button">upload files</div>' +      
                                      '<ul class="qq-upload-list"></ul>' +                  
                                      '</div>',
                            action: '@Url.Action("upload", new { staffId = Model.StaffId })'
                      });
                   </script>
```

Comment: What is the point of adding a prefix to the filename on the client side instead of the server side?

Comment: Why you need the prefix on client? General approach is to add prefix or suffix on the server, after upload.

Comment: sorry, i meant add the prefix in the server side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty simple,

```
public ActionResult SaveFile(HttpPostedFileBase FileUpload)
    {             
      string fileName = "";
      if (FileUpload != null && FileUpload.ContentLength > 0)
        {
          fileName = "123_"+ Path.GetFileName(FileUpload.FileName);
          //rest code
```

Comment: As two Geeks already mentioned in your post that there is no need to add prefix in clientside, i mean in your view. Ok if you want, could you let me know what is the exact requirement ?

Comment: I think i know now , that is exactly what i wanted!! Thanks!!

Comment: Great! Good day :)